# Is Guardians of the Galaxy 3 canceled?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

I remember seeing in the MCU's Wikipedia page that there is going to be another *Guardians Of The Galaxy* movie.

Now I see it's gone and the last one there is *Spider-Man: Far From Home*.

Is it canceled? Where is Phase 4?

Comment: https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/james-gunn-back-as-guardians-galaxy-3-director-1195066

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol._3 is gone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is essentially asking why a wiki site is out of date / not up to date, when the underlying information in the question can easily be found elsewhere (including Wikipedia proper)

Comment: @NKCampbell It may be a poor question and the reasoning for asking may be less than stellar but the actual question is perfectly on topic.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: read responses below

Comment: “Where is Phase 4?” — I’ll do you one better: *why* is Phase 4!?”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only MCU movie that Marvel has formally announced is the final film in Phase Three, *Spider-Man: Far From Home*. However, several of the Phase Four movies are in active development, including *Black Widow*, *The Eternals*, *Shang-Chi* and *Guardians of the Galaxy 3*. The movie is slated to begin filming in 2020 after James Gunn completes his work on *The Suicide Squad* for DC.

Answer (score 8):

James Gunn was fired over old tweets and the future of *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 3* was uncertain. Whilst they still planned to use Gunn's script, some actors went on strike and lots of stuff happened. Safe to say that production was effectively put on hold. However, Gunn has lately been rehired as director and writer and shooting will start in 2020, one year after it was initially supposed to start.

> Redemption and second chances have long been superhero movie staples, and today it looks like life has imitated art. I’ve learned that Disney has reinstated James Gunn as the writer-director of Guardians of the Galaxy 3, and I’ve confirmed it with Marvel and Gunn’s camp.
>
> <sub>[Deadline, Disney Reinstates Director James Gunn For ‘Guardians Of The Galaxy 3’](https://deadline.com/2019/03/james-gunn-reinstated-guardians-of-the-galaxy-3-disney-suicide-squad-2-indefensible-social-media-messages-1202576444/)</sub>

FWIW *Spider-Man: Far From Home* is actually a Phase 3 film and most of the Phase 4 films are only hinted at but not certainly happening yet.

Answer (score 1):

## No.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol._3):

> **Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3**
>
> In April 2016, Kevin Feige stated that "Guardians 3 is [one film that's] up there" being considered for release beyond 2019. In March 2017, Gunn stated that a third Guardians film would happen "for sure", and the following month confirmed he would return to write and direct Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3. However, in July 2018, Disney and Marvel severed ties with Gunn following the resurfacing of controversial tweets from 2008 and 2009 making light of topics such as rape and pedophilia. Marvel planned to continue to use Gunn's script for the film. Production was put on hold in August 2018, ahead of the planned start of filming in January or February 2019. In March 2019, Disney and Marvel reversed course and reinstated Gunn as the director of the film. Filming will begin in 2020 once he has completed his work for the DC Extended Universe film The Suicide Squad.